# jQuery add class to <ul> that is closest to a ".pdf" link

Tags: jquery, closest

```
$("ul:contains('a[href$=.pdf]')").addClass("tragedy");
```

I'm having trouble doing this. I also tried doing this

```
$("ul").closest('a[href$=.pdf]').addClass("tragedy");
```

but it didnt work. If anyone could help me out i would greatly appreciate it

Here's the HTML:

```
<h2>Selected Shakespeare Plays</h2>
      <ul id="selected-plays" class="clear-after">
        <li>Comedies
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/asyoulikeit/">As You Like It</a></li>
            <li>All's Well That Ends Well</li>
            <li>A Midsummer Night's Dream</li>
            <li>Twelfth Night</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Tragedies
          <ul>
            <li><a href="hamlet.pdf">Hamlet</a></li>
            <li>Macbeth</li>
            <li>Romeo and Juliet</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Histories
          <ul>
            <li>Henry IV (<a href="mailto:henryiv@king.co.uk">email</a>)
              <ul>
                <li>Part I</li>
                <li>Part II</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.shakespeare.co.uk/henryv.htm">Henry V</a></li>
            <li>Richard II</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Hard to figure out what the problem is without the html

Comment: sorry i added it in now

Comment: `$("ul:has(a[href$='.pdf'])").addClass("tragedy");` might work.

Comment: thnx guys for the help

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the class to the `<ul>` not to the link itself; flip the order:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').closest('ul').addClass("tragedy");
```

Comment: ahh thanks a lot man. I would vote you up but i dont have 15 rep